# When I refresh the page, my custom Django CMS plugin's children become invalid

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have written the simplest Django CMS plugin possible that allows children (I use Python 3.4.3, Django 1.7.10, Django CMS 3.1.3):

cms_plugins.py:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool

class SamplePlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    allow_children = True
    render_template = "sample_plugin.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['instance'] = instance
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(SamplePlugin)
```

templates/sample_plugin.html:

```
{% load cms_tags %}

{% for plugin in instance.child_plugins %}{% render_plugin plugin %}{% endfor %}
```

I don't use a custom model, just render the child plugins.

I then opened a page in Structure mode and added one instance of that Sampe Plugin and a Style Plugin to a placeholder - so far, so good. I can edit both, of course there is not much to edit for my own plugin. When I now move the Style Plugin into my Sample Plugin, I can still edit the Style Plugin. Switching to content mode and inspecting the DOM, the plugins really are nested.

However, if I now refresh the page, something is clearly inconsistent:

- the `div` corresponding to the Sample Plugin is empty in the DOM
- in Structure mode, the nested Style Plugin no longer shows a context menu
- double clicking it opens the parent Sample Plugin's editor (the DOM shows the parent's id in the iframe source. Manually changing that URL opens the right Editor)
- the Style Plugin can no longer be moved around

A quick inspection of djangocms_style doesn't show any obvious differences that seem relevant to the problem. What's going on here?

---

I'm also getting stack traces similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747840/django-503-service-unavailable), but they seem to be unrelated - it happens when adding any plugin - and don't disrupt anything else - no 503 or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the template, it's supposed to be

```
{% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
```

instead if

```
{% for plugin in instance.child_plugins %}
```

This seems to have changed between Django CMS 2.4 and 3.0: Compare the information on [2.4](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.3/upgrade/2.4.html#how-to-render-your-child-plugins-in-the-template) and [3.0](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.0/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#nested-plugins) (look at `parent.html`)

I have found it's not necessary to override `render` to add `context['instance']`; the Style Plugin doesn't do that either.